# tensorboard with AWS s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, amazon-s3, tensorboard

On linux, with tensorflow/tensorboard 2.9.1, I'm trying to run tensorboard with a folder on a S3 bucket. I'm well authentified: `aws s3 ls` is working. I'm working behind a proxy.
But when I'm running:

```
AWS_LOG_LEVEL=1 AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE=myprofile AWS_REGION=eu-west-1 tensorboard --logdir=s3://mybucket/tensorboard-output/
```

I'm having the following issue:

```
2022-07-11 10:01:18.596111: E tensorflow/c/logging.cc:40] Curl returned error code 77 - Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)
2022-07-11 10:01:18.596228: E tensorflow/c/logging.cc:40] HTTP response code: -1
Resolved remote host IP address: 
Request ID: 
Exception name: 
Error message: curlCode: 77, Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)
0 response headers:
2022-07-11 10:01:18.596256: W tensorflow/c/logging.cc:37] If the signature check failed. This could be because of a time skew. Attempting to adjust the signer.
2022-07-11 10:01:18.596267: W tensorflow/c/logging.cc:37] Request failed, now waiting 0 ms before attempting again.
```

It seems to be an issue with Curl and certificate issue. I already tried to specify the environment variable CURL_CA_BUNDLE= to the right `ca.crt`, but that's not helping, it seems it's not checking this environment variable...

Any idea ? Thank you in advance!